# Replace entire div instead of div contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i am using the following ajax script to replace the contents of a div. But it only changes the contents inside that div. I want to replace the entire div.

```
<script>
function sendmessage()
   {

   var message_content=$("#message").val();

    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "newmessage.php",
          dataType: "html",
          data: {message:message_content},
          success: function(data) {
                    $("#newmessage").html(data); 
              }
        });
   }
   </script>
```

Here contents of id="newmessage" is changed. I want to replace ... with ...

Comment: [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Comment: $("#newmessage").replaceWith(data);  like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use replaceWith

```
<script>
function sendmessage()
   {
   var message_content=$("#message").val();
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "newmessage.php",
          dataType: "html",
          data: {message:message_content},
          success: function(data) {
                    $("#newmessage").replaceWith(data); 
              }
        });
   }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.replaceWith()` :

```
$("#newmessage").replaceWith(data);
```